# Find the cardinal $|P([0,1])\setminus P((0,1))|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm a bit struggling in finding the cardinal size of the set $$|P([0,1])\setminus P((0,1))|$$
Where $P$ is the notation for "power set".

I was thinking about starting with the fact that $(0,1)\cup\{0,1\}=[0,1]$. From there, I could point out that for each $S\in P((0,1))$, there are $S\cup\{0\}, S\cup\{1\},S\cup\{1,0\} \in P([0,1])$. Intuitively, this means that $B=P([0,1])$ is bigger than $A=P((0,1))$ times 4 (for each in A, there is that one in B, plus 3 more).
I have yet to study the arithmetic of set theory, so claiming that $|P([0,1])\setminus P((0,1))| = 2^\aleph \times 3 = 2^\aleph $ is out scope regarding my calculation.

I don't quite know how to move on from here. Moreover, mathematically speaking, I'm a bit confused on how to properly write these claims. As I said, intuitively it seems logical to me that B is 4 times larger than A, but I want to be precise in me writings.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is mean by $|P([0,1])\setminus P((0,1))|$?

Comment: $\forall S\in P([0,1])\setminus P((0,1))$ is it correct to say that S contains either $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @Mason Sure, unless it would have been in $P((0,1))$, which there are none of those. It might contain both $1$ and $0$ also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=P([0,1])$, $B=P((0,1))$, $C=A\setminus B$.
Then we have the following injective maps:
$$ C\to A, s\mapsto s$$
$$ A\to B, s\mapsto \{\,\tfrac{x+1}3\mid x\in s\,\}$$
$$B\to C, s\mapsto \{\,x\cup \{0\} \mid x\in s\,\}$$
From these we conclude that they all have the same cardinality.

Comment: So we only need to have injections here but I I think the thing to do if the OP wants to get a feeling for the size of these things would be to construct a bijection.

Comment: Also you have a kind of nice statement here. We have two sets $A,B$ such that $|A \backslash B|$ is finite but $|P(A) \backslash P(B)|=|P(A)|=|P(B)|$. I wonder what can be said about this in general. How (if at all) is the difference of powersets related to the difference of sets?

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the clarification! :) 
@Mason, I wasn't really thinking about a bijection. Wasn't really thinking about proving this with functions TBH.